# How to show all image from public directory and I try this code but no image to show

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Problem**

I want to show all images from my public folder in laravel 5.2 and try this code but images are not displaying.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
 <?php
            $dirname = "../public/uploads/";
            $images = glob($dirname."*.*");
            for ($i=1; $i<count($images); $i++)

        {

        $image = $images[$i];


         echo '<img width="250" class="all-seletc-wrap" src="'.$image .'"                             
         alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use for your dirname '/uploads' and the rest code is same.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to access the public directory in Laravel is by using the `public_path()` method (see the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-public-path)). Try this instead:

```
$dirname = public_path('uploads');
// rest of your code follows
```